# Creating new module using Angular schematics

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-schematics

We would like to use schematics to generate a feature module that contains components we are generating over and over.

I've started following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@michael.warneke/merging-custom-angular-schematics-c14a303f63b6

But when I created the `__name@dasherize@singularize__.module.ts` file and try to build the project I get TS compilation errors.

This is how my file looks like:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
    ],
    declarations: [],
    providers: [],
    entryComponents: []
 })
export class <%= classify(name) %>Module {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: <%= classify(name) %>Module,
            providers: []
        };
     }
}
```

And this is the error:

> error TS6133: 'ModuleWithProviders' is declared but its value is never read.

Answer (score 0):

From your post, it sounds like this is a compile-time error, i.e., `npm run build` rather than a generation-time error, i.e., `ng new CustomSchematic --collection my-custom-schematic`.

The most frequent culprit I have seen for this behavior is that Typescript is running its validation rules against your schematic assets. In this case, I would expect your `tsconfig.json` to have the following property and value, `"noUnusedLocals": true`. Setting that property to false is probably not a good long time strategy, since it would mean all of your schematic application code no longer executes that validation rule either.

Instead (and what I've chosen to do on my [projects](https://github.com/ericksoen/simple-schematic/blob/master/tsconfig.json)), is to add the following property to the `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"exclude": [
    "src/*/files/**/*"
]
```

This will properly exclude all of your assets underneath your `files` folder of every schematic in your schematic collection.

```
/src
  /ng-new
     /files
        custom-asset.ts
        custom-asset.html
     index.ts
     index_spec.ts
  /custom-service
     /files
        custom-asset.ts
     index.ts
     index_spec.ts
```

I wasn't able to entirely replicate your issue so if you have a public repo link, can you can share it. However, when I remove `excludes` setting in my `tsconfig.json` I go from  compilation to a significant number of Typescript errors, so I have some confidence that this is the right direction.

As one final hint, if you are using VS code and have the **Problems** panel displayed, you can apply the same error suppression strategy using the `!src/*/files/**/*` file path.

[image: Suppress TS errors in schematic assets in VS Code]